# MongoDB - override default Serializer for a C# primitive type

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I'd like to change the representation of C# Doubles to rounded Int64 with a four decimal place shift in the serialization C# Driver's stack for MongoDB. In other words, store (Double)29.99 as (Int64)299900

I'd like this to be transparent to my app. I've had a look at custom serializers but I don't want to override *everything* and then switch on the Type with fallback to the default, as that's a bit messy.

I can see that RegisterSerializer() won't let me add one for an existing type, and that BsonDefaultSerializationProvider has a static list of primitive serializers and it's marked as internal with private members so I can't easily subclass.

I can also see that it's possible to RepresentAs Int64 for Doubles, but this is a cast not a conversion. I need essentially a cast AND a conversion in both serialization directions.

I wish I could just give the default serializer a custom serializer to override one of it's own, but that would mean a dirty hack.

Am I missing a really easy way?

Comment: Added this to the tracker for mongodb's driver: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-587

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can definitely do this, you just have to get the timing right. When the driver starts up there are no serializers registered. When it needs a serializer, it looks it up in the dictionary where it keeps track of the serializers it knows about (i.e. the ones that have been registered). Only it it can't find one in the dictionary does it start figuring out where to get one (including calling the serialization providers) and if it finds one it registers it.

The limitation in RegisterSerializer is there so that you can't *replace* an existing serializer that has already been used. But that doesn't mean you can't register your own *if* you do it early enough.

However, keep in mind that registering a serializer is a global operation, so if you register a custom serializer for double it will be used for *all* doubles, which could lead to unexpected results!

Anyway, you could write the custom serializer something like this:

```cs
public class CustomDoubleSerializer : BsonBaseSerializer
{
    public override object Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, Type actualType, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        var rep = bsonReader.ReadInt64();
        return rep / 100.0;
    }

    public override void Serialize(BsonWriter bsonWriter, Type nominalType, object value, IBsonSerializationOptions options)
    {
        var rep = (long)((double)value * 100);
        bsonWriter.WriteInt64(rep);
    }
}
```

And register it like this:

```cs
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(double), new CustomDoubleSerializer());
```

You could test it using the following class:

```cs
public class C
{
    public int Id;
    public double X;
}
```

and this code:

```cs
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(double), new CustomDoubleSerializer());

var c = new C { Id = 1, X = 29.99 };
var json = c.ToJson();
Console.WriteLine(json);

var r = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<C>(json);
Console.WriteLine(r.X);
```

Comment: OK. So it sounds like you're saying I'd get all the other default serializers but it wouldn't register DoubleSerializer if I've already done so? In terms of "unexpected results", I'd not mind if all my doubles were now Int64 with 4 digit precision but what other "unexpected results" might there be? Would it cause me an issue with Date() for instance or somewhere else? And if so, would it be possible/better to use a custom type altogether instead of either double OR Int64 and but have it serialized AS a primitive type?

Comment: I am actually surprised the static constructor of `BsonSerializer` doesn't fire before any calls to said class itself are made. Quite oddly, you are right though. I'll still go ahead an open an issue on mongodb's issue tracker, maybe an option to overwrite serializers would be nice in the future.

Comment: The static ctor is called before the methods are invoked.  The above behavior described by Robert is not a weird thing.  The static ctor registers serialization providers, which, upon asked, will attempt to provide a serializer.  Hence, because these are delayed registrations of serializers, it is possible to register another serializer to replace the defaults as long as they are registered prior to the first use of the serialization infrastructure.

Comment: So would it be safer to use some other type rather than replacing the double serializer? What "unexpected results" would you expect :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use your own serialization provider to tell Mongo which serializer to use for certain types, which I ended up doing to mitigate some of the timing issues mentioned when trying to override existing serializers. Here's an example of a serialisation provider that overrides how to serialize decimals:

```cs
public class CustomSerializationProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(decimal)) return new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Decimal128);

        return null; // falls back to Mongo defaults
    }
}
```

If you return `null` from your custom serialization provider, it will fall back to using Mongo's default serialization provider.

Once you've written your provider, you just need to register it:

```cs
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new CustomSerializationProvider());
```

Comment: The accepted answer is very hard to work with using dependency injection, but this works like a charm.

Comment: This was the magic for me, combined with the custom serializer. I upvoted it. It totally deserves it.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the latest iteration of the driver's code and checked if there's some sort of backdoor to set custom serializers. I am afraid there's none; you should open an issue in the project's bug tracker if you think this needs to be looked at for future iterations of the driver (https://jira.mongodb.org/).

Personally, I'd open a ticket -- and if a quick workaround is necessary or required, I'd subclass DoubleSerializer, implement the new behavior, and then use Reflection to inject it into either `MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DoubleSerializer.__instance` or `MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonDefaultSerializationProvider.__serializers`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd figured. You have an interesting idea though. It's not pretty and possibly fragile, but interesting.

Comment: I suppose a less quirky way would be to simply fire up git, fork the official driver repository and implement your changes there: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver